# My van is at 89K miles right now. It is losing its pickup

Tags: dodge, acceleration, grand-caravan

I have a Dodge Grand Caravan 2012 and it is losing its pickup. I know the dealership changed the air-filter last time I went for an oil change.

I have always been regular on the manufacturer recommended maintenance.
So what could be a reason for this?

Comment: You have two separate questions here: one concerning how the vehicle is running; the second about how well the ac is working. Could you please edit this question, limiting it to a single question, then open a separate question to deal with your separate issue? Also, please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: We would only be guessing since you have not posted the maintenance history for the vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

There are many potential reasons for this.  Bear in mind that all engines lose power as they accumulate mileage, due to gradual loss of compression from wear on the piston rings.  Incorrect fuel, a timing problem, a malfunctioning sensor , the list goes on and on.